# How to use cacheSend of drizzle library when the method needs two parameters

Tags: solidity, truffle, drizzle

Should it be like the example below(2,2 as two different parametres)
Ex: const stackId = drizzle.contracts.SimpleStorage.methods.set.cacheSend(2,2, {from: '0x3f...'})

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way of doing multiple parameters. See [here](https://gitter.im/ConsenSys/truffle?at=5d796781c59390272054713f) where somebody asked a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is sending them as parameters to `cacheSend`:

```
cacheSend(
      drizzleState.clientAccount,
      toHex(parseAmountToToken(amountToSend, tokenDecimals))
    );
```

Here, we are sending two parameters for the `transfer` function: `transfer(address, uint256)...`.

If you are using hooks you can use the `send` function passing the parameters you need:

```
const { useCacheSend } = drizzleReactHooks.useDrizzle()
const { send, TXObjects } = useCacheSend('MyToken', 'transfer')

---

        onSubmit={
          // Use memoization to avoid unnecessary rerenders.
          useCallback(({ to=drizzleState.clientAccount, value=toHex(parseAmountToToken(amountToSend, tokenDecimals)) }) => send(to, value), [amountToSend])
        }
```

That's all.